# Why has my phone locked me out?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, locked-out, malware

I would add photos of what it says but it won't let me.

It's telling me that I have illegal content on my phone yet I don't to my knowledge, and I can leave the screen that it is locked on to check.

I just think it a virus but it will not let me check for viruses.

I have tried restarting it and removing the battery as that's all that it is letting me do.

Comment: Give us the screenshots? Which Android version are you using? Is the Android rooted?

Comment: Sounds like [Ransomware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ransomware) to me. Afraid you've got to [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) to get rid of that. Installed any thing from "other sources" lately? Or clicked some "urgent banners" (fake WhatsApp update, "you've-got-a-virus-click-here-to-fix" stuff, or the like)?